# Magento htaccess 301 Redirects

Tags: .htaccess, magento

We've got a Magento site we're trying to launch. We've got a whole bunch of URL rewrites, but when I add then to the .htaccess files, the site doesn't load.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, here's the code I'm using:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^StoreLevel=3&PrevStoreLevel=1&productid=6067&Level1=155&p=5&term=&BrowseBy=0$
RewriteRule ^store\.php$ http://oursite.com/zproduct.html? [R=301,L]
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what error messages are you getting?

Comment: Heh, yeah that would probably be helpful info, I get: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: turn on rewrite error logging and post what output you get.  `RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 9`

Comment: Tried that, pasted at the top of the file: ############################################
RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log RewriteLogLevel 9
############################################ The server kicked back a 500 error on this

Comment: are you putting it in the vhost conf? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: btw, I'm editing the .htaccess file from Magento, not sure if that makes a difference here. Appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean here, trying to figure it out. I checked that link, but I'm not sure how to access vhost conf, sorry for my confusion

Comment: unfortunately it won't work in the .htaccess.  you need to place the directive in the apache configuration http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Answer (score 0):

Is mod_rewrite enabled? You can make .htaccess files a little more bullet-proof with some conditionals, like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^StoreLevel=3&PrevStoreLevel=1&productid=6067&Level1=155&p=5&term=&BrowseBy=0$
    RewriteRule ^store\.php$ zproduct.html [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also note that you don't need to put in the full URL if your redirection stays on the same domain.

By the way, if you are just doing basic string matching then there is no point in using a regular expression. There is a [page on the Apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond) which gives a brief overview of alternatives to using a regex, you might want something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =StoreLevel=3&PrevStoreLevel=1&productid=6067&Level1=155&p=5&term=&BrowseBy=0
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem, using the full URL seemed to be causing probs as well. Now in regards to the formatting these more efficiently, we have like 1000 of them so it's key that we do this. Does this look right to you? <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =Store.php?StoreLevel=3&PrevStoreLevel=1&productid=6067&Level1=155&p=5&term=&BrowseBy=0
    RewriteRule zproduct.html [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: No, QUERY_STRING only includes the query string to match against, so you should omit the Store.php? from the RewriteCond. Otherwise it looks good to me. If my answer solves your problem please accept it! ;)